# php form - multiple drop down menus

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am using the following code to update my database from a drop down menu pulling information from another table

```
<?php
$query = "select id, accountname from reg";
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

echo '<select id="domain_account" name="domain_account">';
echo '<option value="">';
echo  $row['domain_account'];
echo  '</option>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['accountname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['accountname']; ?></option>
<?php    
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

The problem is that if i have 2 or more drop down elements only the top one reads the current record

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fire another query to populate the next selection box.
Or you can save the current query results in a variable and reuse that.

Comment: could you please give a example

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $query = "select id, accountname from reg";
    $result = $mysqli->query( $query );

    echo '<select id="domain_account" name="domain_account">';
    echo '<option value="">';
    echo  $row['domain_account'];
    echo  '</option>';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo '<option value="'.$row["accountname"].'">'.$row["accountname"].'</option>';
    } 
    echo '</select>';
 ?>
```

That should already solve the issue you would have of breaking you `while` loop.
But your code seems incomplete: where do you get your `domain_account` field? Where is your request?

Comment: `echo '<option value=".$row["accountname"].'">'.$row["accountname"].'</option>';` < that really, won't work ... `' ... '` denotes a string literal and will treat `$row` well, literally.

Comment: Oops, changed the quotes mid-way. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $all_rows[] = $row;
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['accountname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['accountname']; ?></option>
<?php    
}
echo "</select>";

foreach($all_rows as $row) {
    //do stuff with $row like echo $row['something'];
}
```